Vue - динамичное обновление заголовка
Как лучше реализовать обновление заголовка в компоненте хэдера?
Информация о заголовке хранится на каждой странице.
Не хотелось бы на из лайаута выносить компонент хэдера и вставлять на каждую страницу и пропсами перекидывать заголовок в него. Может использовать portal или доп область через vue-router добавить.

{{переменная, где хранится имя}} }}}
В переменную при смене компонента "заносим" его имя.
@Михаил Не совсем понял.
Header.vue
`
Судя по всему - вы совсем "начинающий" - тогда путь простой - найдите Уроки на Тюбике и методично смотрите и учитесь. По другому - потратите много времени.
Например очень хорошо излагает все Дмитрий Лаврик.

@Михаил Спасибо. А можно все таки как то перефразировать решение или дополнить описание одним, двумя словами? Возможно я в описании проблемы что то намудрил.

@Михаил Как я буду брать имя компонента, если его vue-router автоматом меняет в зависимости от url, ну допустим я найду вариант, и что мне даст имя компонента, когда мне нужны данные из этого компонента? Мне нужно взять заголовок из компонента и закинуть его в отдельный независимый компонент хэдера. Я вижу варианты только с хранением данных, через composable или provide/inject. А ваш вариант похож на динамичные компоненты, но как он здесь применим я не могу понять. Если конечно я не ввел вас в заблуждение не ясным описанием к проблеме.

Если в роутере имя передается как параметр /:имя - (посмотрите console.log(router.params что у вас передается) возьмите этот параметр в Header просто. Или другим путем в Главном Компоненте сохраняйте этот параметр после router update и provide/inject получайте его в Любом компоненте.
import { useRoute,  useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()

@Михаил Ага, спасибо!
